# deploy angular in aws Elastic Beanstalk 502 stauts code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, angular7

Cannot deploy my angular 7 project in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I could deploy my express project, any idea?

This is the Request.

```
Request URL: http://mingzhi-event-search.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/favicon.ico
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway
Remote Address: 18.223.167.56:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 575
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2018 10:39:03 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: mingzhi-event-search.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://mingzhi-event-search.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: And the error occur: Following services are not running: application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a front-end engine, not a server. If you wanna deploy an Angular application on AWS without a server, you should store the application in a Bucket and properly set the permissions.

Otherwise, you have to set up a server (e.g. a NodeJS application, but whatever) and deploy it using Elastic BeanStalk.

Comment: I have already set up a back end NodeJS server, the angular application is just send get request to my server

Comment: Thank you, this is the real problem!